# Removing a class from parent element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out how to remove a class from a parent element when the element has begun dragging.

Meaning I have `<div>` elements in a table cell and I want to remove the class "contains_piece" from the table cell once the `<div>` has started being dragged.

I'm using jQuery to add the class to the cell that the div has been dropped on but cannot figure out how to work out this problem.

Comment: Please provide some code of what you've done so far.

Comment: If you're using some jQuery plugin also mention what exactly it might already support what you want.

Comment: What's your problem? To get the parent or to remove the class? Both are perfectly described in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: I wasnt using any plugin, simply trying to make a table where i can drage elements into but not if it already has an element in it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(element).parent().removeClass('something');
```

Like this?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be     `.parent().removeClass('contains_piece');` ?